# Delete CustomXml files -docx4j

Tags: docx4j

How to delete custom XML files with its property and relationship files?, I've used clear() method. But it's not working. Help me out.

```
wordMLPackage.getCustomXmlDataStorageParts().clear();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/docx4j-core/src/main/java/org/docx4j/Docx4J.java#L643 shows you how to do this.  To remove them all, it would be:

```
protected static void removeDefinedCustomXmlParts(WordprocessingMLPackage wmlPackage) {
List<PartName> partsToRemove = new ArrayList<PartName>();
RelationshipsPart relationshipsPart = wmlPackage.getMainDocumentPart().getRelationshipsPart();
List<Relationship> relationshipsList = ((relationshipsPart != null) && 
                                        (relationshipsPart.getRelationships() != null) ?
                                        relationshipsPart.getRelationships().getRelationship() : null);
Part part = null;
    if (relationshipsList != null) {
        for (Relationship relationship : relationshipsList) {
            if (Namespaces.CUSTOM_XML_DATA_STORAGE.equals(relationship.getType())) {
                part = relationshipsPart.getPart(relationship);
                partsToRemove.add(part.getPartName());
            }
        }
    }
    if (!partsToRemove.isEmpty()) {
        for (int i=0; i<partsToRemove.size(); i++) {
            relationshipsPart.removePart(partsToRemove.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```